# Site scraping in perl using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, authentication, web, mechanize, scrape

I have used WWW::Mechanize in perl for site scraping application.

I have faced some difficulties when I'm going to login to particular site via WWW::Mechanize. I have gone through some examples of WWW::Mechanize. But i couldn't find out my issue. 
I have mention below my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use Crypt::SSLeay;
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(noproxy => 0);
$agent->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$agent->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
$agent->proxy(['https', 'http', 'ftp'], 'http://proxy.rcapl.com:3128');
$agent->get("http://www.facebook.com");
my $re=$agent->submit_form(
        form_number => 1,
        fields      => {
            Email    => 'xyz@gmail.com',
            Passwd  =>'xyz'
        }
    );
print $re->content();
```

When i run the code it says:

Error POSTing https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1: Not Implemented at ./test.pl line 11

Can anybody tell what's going wrong on code. Do i need to set all the parameters which facebook send for login?.

Comment: sure, I did it.Thank you for put me to correct path

Comment: @daxim : I removed proxy method and run it.Then it comes: Error POSTing https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1: Can't connect to proxy.rcapl.com:3128 (Bad service '3128/') at .. Is there any place that get proxy settings. Im working on ubuntu and i run through the terminal. Still I'm in trouble.can you tell where i miss ?

Comment: @daxim : Fixed the Error. What you said is true.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy is faulty:

```
Error GETing http://www.facebook.com: Can't connect to proxy.rcapl.com:3128 (Bad hostname) at so11406791.pl line 11.
```

The program works for me without calling the proxy method. Remove this.

Comment: Moved previous speculative answer from comment section after confirmation.